# Wait for subscription of void method

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm fairly new to rxjs and i'm having troubles with observables.

Before navigating to the next page i need to validate that the total has not changed, usually the method calculateTotal is called asynchronously as you add items.
But before continuing to the next page i want to make sure the current transaction total is correct.

This is not exactly the code but more or less represents what i want to do.

```
public navigateToNextStep() {
    if (isTransactionValid()) {
        this.router.navigate([CodeClient.RoutingToDetailsPage]);
    }
}
private isTransactionValid() {
    let total = this.transaction.Total;

    this.calculateTotal(); //need to wait for this to finish

    if (total == this.transaction.Total) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that i need to find a way to wair for calculateTotal() to finish before going to the next step.

```
private calculateTotal() {
    this.transactionService.calculateTotal(this.transaction).subscribe(
        (result) => {
            this.transaction.Total = result.Total;
            }
    );
}
```

transactionService

```
public calculateTotal(trans: Trans): Observable<TotalResult> {
    return this.http.post<TotalResult>(this.api_url, Trans);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide us more detail and code for  `calculateTotal ` ?

Comment: The transactionService.calculate total is just an http.post call to the api, there is a lot of data that needs to be passed and validated in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello @Daniel your behavior is really close to `promise` approch, you can do something like this, is not the cleanest way but is just simple sample to show you how you can deal with full home made Observable.

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subscriber} from 'rxjs/Subscriber';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit {

    obs: Subscriber<number>;
    calculate$: Observable<number>;

    price: number = null;
    quantity: number = null;

    ngOnInit() {
        //We craft home made observable.
        this.calculate$ = Observable.create((obs) => {
            //We keep reference of Observer as attribut of class.
            this.obs = obs; 
            //We init first value as null.
            this.obs.next(null);    
        });  
    }

    private validate() {
        //We assume we consider as valid, any value differente than null.
        if (this.price !== null && this.quantity !== null) 
        {
            //We next new data.
            this.obs.next(this.price * this.quantity);
            //We complete this observable because we don't need it anymore.
            this.obs.complete();
        }
    }

    onPriceHandler() 
    {
        // Possible case of validation.
        this.validate();
    }

    onQuantityHandler() 
    {
        // Possible case of validation.
        this.validate();
    }
}
```

Html side :

```
<p>Price :</p>
<input type="number" name="price" [(ngModel)]="price" (change)="onPriceHandler()">
<br>
<p>Quantity :</p>
<input type="number" name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="quantity" (change)="onQuantityHandler()">
<br>
<!-- We don't display "go to next step" button until we have not validate -->
<button *ngIf="(calculate$ | async) !== null"> go next step</button>
```

[Live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-geh3bt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**_ EDIT 1 _**

On my case, is better to use `BehaviorSubject`, small update have to be done :

```
price: number = null;
quantity: number = null;
isValid$ : BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
    // We init our observable by false, by default is not valid.
    this.isValid$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
}

private validate() {
    //We assume we consider as valid, any value differente than null.
    if (this.price !== null && this.quantity !== null) 
    {
        //We next new data.
        this.isValid$.next(true);
        //We complete this observable because we don't need it anymore.
        this.isValid$.complete();
    }
}
```

Html side : 
     go next step

[Live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yi5hvy?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Check the condition in subscribe method.

```
public navigateToNextStep() {
    let total = this.transaction.Total;
    this.transactionService.calculateTotal(this.transaction).subscribe(
        (result) => {
            this.transaction.Total = result.Total;
            if (total == this.transaction.Total) {
                this.router.navigate([CodeClient.RoutingToDetailsPage]);
            }

        }
    );
}
```